# In WPf grid panel if items exceeds one column it should add at next column

Tags: wpf

In Custom control i need to create a grid panel, in that i splitted 3 columns and 2 rows. if the items exceeds one column the next items should be added at next column

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need something specialized that `Grid`. Try out different panels. I would suggest `WrapPanel` or `UniformGrid`. You could also put a `Horizontal` `StackPanel` inside each row.

If nothing works out for you, you can always create a custom panel.

It would be better if you posted you scenario here.